# Seek and pause video stream from ffserver

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, ffserver

I managed to successfully feed **ffserver** from **ffmpeg**. **ffmpeg** takes input as PIPE:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel fatal -f image2pipe -re -vcodec png -i - -vcodec libx264 http://localhost:8090/%s.ffm
```

External **java** process generates *svg/png* images and pushes to **ffpmepg**

My **ffserver** config allows me to buffer live feeds in *ffm* file without defining the size of the file.

My *stream* configuration looks like this:

```
<Stream live2.mjpg>
   Feed feed2.ffm
   Format mpjpeg
   VideoFrameRate 25
   VideoSize 640x880
   VideoQMin 1
   VideoQMax 5
   NoAudio
   Strict -1
</Stream>
```

The problem is that, despite that I can watch streams in **VLC** by opening network:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8090/live2.mjpg
```

But I can not seek through already buffered movie.
Is there a way to achieve seeking through movie, pausing, and resume playing from "**now**"? I have tried already **rtsp** with **h264**, **mpg** and **sdp** but without success:

```
<Stream test1.mpg/sdp/h264>
   Format rtp
   Feed feed2.ffm
   VideoCodec libx264
   VideoSize 640x880
   VideoQMin 1
   VideoQMax 5
   NoAudio
   Strict -1
   VideoFrameRate 25
</Stream>
```

Is **rtsp** solution for this problem, or I need something else?

Can this be achieved from *dynamic* file since I am using PIPE?

Comment: There is no format supported by FFmpeg named `mpjpeg`. I believe you meant `mjpeg`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard There seems to be a format like that: ` E mpjpeg    MIME multipart JPEG`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard according to https://www.ffmpeg.org/sample.html in example streams there is 'Format mpjpeg'. Is this a typo? This stream works.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I had "codec" in my mind, specifically "encoder" (although I even wrote format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **RTSP**

  RTSP support in `ffserver` seems a bit sketchy, you could try [Darwin Streaming Server](http://dss.macosforge.org/) or the [Live555 media server](http://www.live555.com/). The two seem to support some forms of trick-play at least for VOD. Since you're using a pipe this won't probably help.
- **RTMP**

  Some RTMP servers/clients support in-buffer seeking (**Smart Seeking**).

  > **About Smart Seek**
  >
  > Adobe Media Server 3.5.3 and Flash Player 10.1 work together to
  >   support smart seeking in VOD streams and in live streams that have a
  >   buffer.   [[Source](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/dev/smart-seeking.html)].

  `ffserver` doesn't support RTMP output but you can use your `ffmpeg` command to push your stream directly to the server:

  `ffmpeg -re -i <input> -f flv rtmp://...`

  There's a [Nginx RTMP module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) and a [C++ RTMP](http://www.rtmpd.com/) server although it's not very clear if they support smart seeking. VLC seems to be able to seek a bit while paused and there are usually options to modify the size of the client RTMP buffer.